# Criar tabela temporária a partir dos dados de um cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

Criei um cursor que mostra a data da venda e o valor total vendido do dia. Segue o código:

```
declare cursorteste cursor
local forward_only
for select data_venda, sum(valor_unitario) as valor_unitario from venda v, produtoVenda pv
where v.id_venda = pv.id_venda
group by data_venda

open cursorteste
declare @data_venda date, @total decimal(10,2)

fetch cursorteste into @data_venda, @total
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        select @data_venda as data_venda, @total as _total
        fetch next from cursorteste into @data_venda, @total
    end

close cursorteste
deallocate cursorteste
```

Até ai tudo OK, o problema vem agora..

Agora a partir desse cursor, preciso criar uma tabela temporária que tenha a data da venda, o valor total vendido no dia e a situação do dia. Por exemplo:

***Menor*** - significa que as vendas do dia atual foram menores que as vendas do dia anterior

***Normal*** - significa que as vendas do dia atual foram iguais as vendas do dia anterior

***Maior*** - significa que as vendas do dia atual foram maiores que as vendas do dia anterior

Sei que para criar tabelas temporárias preciso usar #tabela_temporaria. Fuçei por vários blogs e pela documentação da Microsoft, e não consegui localizar nada a respeito disso ou eu não consegui me expressar direito sobre o que estava procurando.

Como eu crio essa tabela temporária a partir desse cursor? Como crio essa condição de situação do dia atual, se baseando no dia anterior?

Se alguém puder compartilhar comigo. Valeu galera!!

Comment: Leia sobre analytic funtions , lead e lag permitem este tipo de comparação ... https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/analytic-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 ...   https://www.ti-enxame.com/pt/sql/subtrair-linha-anterior-para-calcular-o-valor-da-coluna-no-ms-sql/816476772/  ... este é um caso real ou acadêmico ?

Comment: Voce nao precisa de um cursor para essa query. Voce pode fazer tudo com um select.

Answer (score 0):

Opa. Fala cara!

A um tempo atrás, passei por isto. Não é o melhor jeito, mas você pode tentar adaptar isto aqui:

[Essa pergunta de Cursor com Tabela temporária](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24915301/in-sql-server-how-do-you-put-value-from-cursor-into-temp-table)

No meu caso, eu precisava armazenar cursores numa tabela temporária. Te recomendo, ver uma possível estrutura de uma PROCEDURE.

Comment: E o perguntador some ...